# Virtualize Windows on Fedora and let Windows see real hardware

Tags: fedora, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hardware

My question may be weird. I want to know if there is some virtual machine that lets me install Windows 7 under Linux and lets Windows use, as a virtual device, the same device that is really installed in my physical PC.

I need to do that, because of a lot of Adobe software that I need for work and I can't switch to other software (even if I'd like to).

Maybe what I need could be something even simpler, like letting the virtual machine see the graphics card I have to get the full compatibility with the Adobe software and the OpenGL and DirectX drivers.

Actually I use VirtualBox to run Windows, and Fedora is my main OS.

The hardware that I need to share is as follows:
⠀CPU - Intel Core i7 990x (even only a subset of all the cores)
⠀GPU - Nvidia Quadro 2000

Comment: May be you can try quick emulator (QEMU)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are slightly more adventurous and/or @slm's answer and 2D/3D accelaration is not enough, you can look at PCIe passthrough. 
You need two graphics adapters for that (one possible being onboard) and multiple monitors (or multiple inputs to one monitor).

There are more details on the requirements of the graphics adapter on the [virtualbox site](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=46450)

I looked into this some time ago when I wanted to add a 3rd monitor in portrait mode to the two I already had in landscape mode. However it did not work out for me as my graphics card did not fulfill the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 products you can use to virtualize Windows under Linux.

- VMware
- VirtualBox
- KVM

Since you're already using VirtualBox I would say you're 90% of the way there. You need to install the software you want into your Windows VM and expose access to the various hardware to the VM so that it can have exclusive control of the device.

You can do this explicitly with USB devices, for example. For video hardware it's a little more difficult but should be possible. You'll likely have to enable different options through the VirtualBox management GUI to allow for more intimate access to the underlying hardware, if you're attempting to get better performance within the VM.

Realize too that often times you can't get the exact performance from a VM that you'd get from a bare metal installation, and you may have to resort to doing a dual boot installation if performance becomes a limiting factor within the Windows VM.

Comment: do you know how I can enable this features in virtual box?
or, at least, can you link some trusted resources where I can study how to do that?

Comment: You can enable 2D and 3D accelaration in the "Display" settings of the virtual machine in VirtualBox

Comment: @AndreaRastelli - as Anthon has suggested is the method I had in mind.

Comment: I have done all of this already.. but at least I'm doing something wrong, in window I see the GPU as "virtual graphic device" (or something like that). If the 3D-stuff is checked, in windows something goes wrong and I can't use all the 3D acceleration I need.